# Source about a king like Haman if Israel doesn't repent

Tags: sources-mekorot, repentance-teshuvah, haman

I'm writing an article about the holocaust and I want to find a source that says if Israel does not repent, Hashem will raise up a king like Haman.

Answer (score 8):

[Sanhedrin 97b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.97b.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> If they do not repent, will they not be redeemed at all? Rather, the Holy One, Blessed be He, will establish a king for them whose decrees are as harsh as those issued by Haman, and the Jewish people will have no choice but to repent

Comment: ואמר רבי יוחנן אין בן דוד בא אלא בדור שכולו זכאי או כולו חייב בדור שכולו זכאי דכתיב (ישעיהו ס, כא) ועמך כולם צדיקים לעולם יירשו ארץ בדור שכולו חייב דכתיב (ישעיהו נט, טז) וירא כי אין איש וישתומם כי אין מפגיע וכתיב (ישעיהו מח, יא) למעני אעשה  so it is not that clear Some say pshat that people will be either fully frum or fully not frum. There will be non-repentent who will be redeemed.

Comment: @interested Agreed, I wasn't providing a comprehensive opinion, just the source as requested